# Why for the equivalent temperature of an energy, one uses $E=k_BT$ instead of $E=3/2 k_BT$?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, dimensional-analysis, large-hadron-collider

In the question : 
[Relationship between temperature and energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/130647/relationship-between-temperature-and-energy)

The relation between energy and temperature is given : $(1/2)k_BT$ per degree of freedom.

Then the one that gives the accepted answer gives further comments on the energy at particle colliders like LHC, and say that one uses $E=k_B T$.

Why for the equivalent temperature of an energy, one uses $E=k_BT$ instead of $E=(3/2)k_BT$ : why the factor $3/2$ disappears for the relationship at an accelerator ?

Comment: The relation $E=1/2 k_BT$ per degree of freedom only refers to kinetic energy (it's not the answer to your question, just a clarification).

Comment: @Felipe : thank you very much. It clarifies a lot the interpretation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that, in the cited post, he's only giving a relation such that you can speak about temperatures as energy and viceversa. The direct conversion between the two is given by $E=k_bT$ and you can easily see why if you take something like a Boltzmann distribution $$P \propto e^{-\Delta E/k_bT}$$ if you want to have an adimensional parameter at the exponent, you clearly want that $k_bT$ has dimension of energy, which in fact it has. It's a useful way of computing quantities knowing that $300K$ are about $25$ meV.

The formula that you gave $E=\frac{3}{2}k_bT$ gives you the energy of a $3$-dimensional free gas at temperature $T$, which is quite specific. That relation also depends on the number of square degrees of freedom of the system. The first formula is more "general", to say. It doesn't pretend to give you the exact energy of a specific system, it just converts kelvin to Joules, or electronvolts and such.

Comment: Thank you, but sorry : why the relationship $E=(3/2)k_bT$ would be different for the case of a 3-dimensional free gas with respect to an accelerator ? In the accelerator, we still have particles, so somehow, they represent a gaz. They go in one direction, so still, there should a term $1/2$ somewhere ?

Comment: The constant term is irrelevant. We're not trying to give the exact thermal energy of an accelerated particle, which it does not have, we just want to give a temperature equivalent of the energy of an accelerated particle. This is not saying that if you go inside an accelerator you'll measure $x$ amount of temperature, it's just a useful conversion

Comment: All right. Thank you Davide for your generous explanations.